# How to do ServiceStack auth with MVC without EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, oauth, openid, servicestack

I'm working through the example [`AccountController`](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.UseCases/blob/master/CustomAuthenticationMvc/Controllers/AccountController.cs) and trying to implement my own. I'm trying to do OAuth (via GMail) and so I've got it working all the way through `ExternalLoginCallback(string)`. The example does `OAuthWebSecurity.Login`. When I try to also do that, I get:

```
You must call the "WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection" method before you call any other method of the "WebSecurity" class.
```

After digging in, it appears that `InitializeDatabaseConnection` uses Entity Framework to configure a database on SQL Server. I'm not using SQL Server (Mongo DB), so I can't use this method. **How do I use ServiceStack auth with MVC and no SQL Server?**